# c++ LibAV How to re-encode flac so that it can be packetize in less than 1500 bytes (MTU size for RTP)

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

I am getting flac codec data from upstream and need to re-transmit through RTP in the same format. Using ffmpeg libav (c++) ,how can I get the AVPacket of flac data for less than 1500 byte so that I can send it through RTP.

Comment: Lossless and max size are contradictory requirements. You’ll have to split it into multiple UDP packets if it’s too big.